# how to setup snmptraps to automatically report ports that when down due to 'err-disabled'?

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, snmp

I'd like to automatically monitor all ports on my switches and get notified whenever a port goes down. So far I have to connect to each switch manually and read out the disabled ports by hand:

```
show interfaces status err-disabled
```

I'd much prefer if ports that went down would get automatically reported to nagios. Based on my preliminary [research](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/servers-unified-computing/ucs-manager/112003-ucsm-faults-report-snmp-traps-00.html), it appears that I need to configure `snmp-traps`.

My questions:

- what are the commands that I need to execute to automatically detect `err-disabled` events and send the switch name, port name (gigabitEthernetx/y/z) as well as the reason for the error (security violation, loop detected, etc) to nagios?
- do I need to configure this on each switch that belongs to a stack, or can I do this on a master switch?

Answer (score -2):

You're going to have to do a bit of configuration, but there is a guide here that should work for you (http://askaralikhan.blogspot.com/2010/12/receiving-snmp-traps-in-nagios.html).

As long as you are comfortable getting snmptrapd up and running you shouldn't have any problems with following the guide.

Comment: This site is not about blog promotion. Please post the contents of the recipe here.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to address my problem. I only want to detect these error events mentioned above and automatically detect the affected ports.